# Mysql начать поиск с конца

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

Всем привет. Обычно когда мы делаем поиск в таблице Mysql все операции select начинаются с 1 id.
У меня есть таблица session с данными около 6млн, в них есть ячейка campany. Мне нужно найти id последней сессии определенной campany.

Когда я делаю

```
SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE campany=1 limit 1
```

запрос занял **0.0004** сек

А вот когда добавляю order

```
SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE campany=1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1
```

Запрос занял **23.4116** сек

Как я понимаю селектор начал с начала таблицы, выбрал всех кто WHERE campany=1, а уже потом сделал манипуляцию ORDER BY id DESC. Ну в таких объемах это не только медленно, но и оперативку кушает прилично

Логично предположить что есть альтернатива которая начинает операцию не с начала, а с конца, но в документации Mysql, я такого не нашел. Может кто знает хитрости и посоветует как оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: *Обычно когда мы делаем поиск в таблице Mysql все операции select начинаются с 1 id.* Бред. *А вот когда добавляю order* Попытка сравнивать неэквивалентные запросы - бессмысленное занятие. *Запрос занял 23.4116 сек* Нет подходящего индекса -> фуллскан -> долго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если часто нужно обращаться и знать ID последней записи, можно при создании этой записи через триггер фиксировать ID в отдельной таблице со служебными константами.

Или, если габариты БД позволяют, попробуйте так:

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions` ADD INDEX ( `id` DESC ) ;
```

Comment: Пробовал, в итоге добавил индекс для кампаний и использовал  USE INDEX. Сократил запрос до секунды

SELECT id FROM sessions USE INDEX (campany) WHERE campany=1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1

Comment: @Art Так же попробуйте индекс из двух полей `(campany, id)` и делайте order by campany, id desc возможно еще быстрее будет. Да и use index не обязательно писать оптимизатор сам должен понять как ему работать